# Authorize app comes each time while posting tweet in android application

Tags: android, twitter

In my application some texts are posting in the Twitter. Each time while posting in the twitter "Authorize app" comes and user have to authorize the application each time while posting text in the twitter. I want user have to authorize the application for the first time not the each time. I have used the twitter sample code from the github. Please help me to solve the issues. Thanks.

Comment: Check out socialauth android library. The latest sdk resolves authorize app issue for twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) library, it's listed on the official site (has unofficial status though)

You most likely are using twitter-android-sdk which can only auth over WebView, which is very limiting.

The up-to-date way to use Twitter API is to use oAuth and Twitter4j can do that, check out the link above, it has examples.

**UPD**

Also, if posting to Twitter is not your app's main purpose (like you want to give the user the ability to share something but they won't be doing so 60% of the time), you're better off using an Intent broadcast to share your content - that way if user has Twitter app installed, they won't have to authorize in your app at all, more details [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) and [here if you are targeting API14+](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)